# React js server start taking long time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server

I have react js application which is taking long time to start, and I see below check is performed during the start up, which is causing the server to take time to load.

```
 Line 19:10:   'data' is assigned a value but never used                no-unused-vars
 Line 58:13:   Nested block is redundant                                no-lone-blocks
 Line 98:52:   Expected to return a value in arrow function             array-callback-return
 Line 154:34:  Expected to return a value in arrow function             array-callback-return
 Line 156:41:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return
 Line 158:54:  Unnecessarily computed property ["pumpError"] found      no-useless-computed-key
 Line 162:54:  Unnecessarily computed property ["pumpError"] found      no-useless-computed-key
 Line 166:54:  Unnecessarily computed property ["pumpError"] found      no-useless-computed-key
 Line 185:50:  Unnecessarily computed property ["pumpError"] found      no-useless-computed-key
```

I want to skip this and searched for any option available to skip this and make loading faster, both in dev and production build, but in vain. Is it possible to skip this in react js during server start up?.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: no server, i am just using npm start alone

Comment: Turn off your linting? But linting shouldn't take that long.